# Contem Valor não definido SQL

Tags: sql

Olá, estou em dúvida em uma consulta SQL, tenho que fazer uma consulta para filtrar um campo que contenha mais de um valor por exemplo 10001-10002 só que este campo não possui um valor fixo, depende de qual código o sistema irá gerar, pensei em algo usando a Função LIKE `WHERE RES_EVENT LIKE  '%'+ TRA_UDFCHAR05 + '%'`, só que não está funcionando porque eu tenho valores variáveis, esse campo em um momento pode ser preenchido com 10001 - 10003 outra hora 11000 - 12344 nunca ira repetir este código

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: pq não `RES_EVENT IN (10001,10002)` ou se quiser todos os valores no intervalo `RES_EVENT BETWEEN 10001 AND 10002`?

Comment: Ricardo, ficou vago minha explicação me desculpe, esse campo não possui um valor fixo pode mudar como 10006 - 10008, depende do código que nosso sistema ira gerar.

Comment: Onde é preenchido esse valor é o campo TRA_UDFCHAR05

Comment: Não diz o SGBD tente algo como o INSTR do Oracle ou Mysql ... maior que 0 .... https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_instr.asp

Answer (score -1):

Se você quer usar mais de uma condição então podes usar [operadores lógicos](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_operators.asp) (como o AND) dentro do WHERE.

```sql
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE genero = “F” AND nome LIKE “R%”
```

Neste comando, todos os clientes do gênero feminino com nomes que iniciam com R serão retornados.

Comment: Rafael, desculpe me, detalhei meu questionamento novamente..